# how to solve zoom level css on mac chrome browser?

Tags: css

I am working on a website but there is an issue which is mention below.
I am using a media query for different-2 zoom level like in 25 %, 50% for chrome browser but it is not working on chrome mac browser properly.
25% zoom level media query on windows chrome is working on 33% zoom level on mac chrome
.please help

Comment: Is the mac display retina? Might be related.

Comment: yes I think the display is retina but not sure

Comment: All Macs from 2013 or later have retina screens.

Comment: then it should have retina display because this is 2017 model

Comment: is there any specific styles property or media query for retina screen?

Comment: Could you post your media queries here?

Comment: @media (min-width:4103px) and (max-width:5464px)
  {
  
  .subMenus {
      line-height: 1.20;
  }                                                                                                             
           }

Comment: thi above media query i   am using for 25% zoom level and this is working only on windows chrome but i also need this for mac chrome also

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem stems from 25% zoom on non retina equaling 33% zoom on retina.
My suggestion would be to adjust your media query to the differences manually.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/

```
@media (min-width: YOUR_RETINA_MIN_WIDTH) and (max-width: YOUR_RETINA_MAX_WIDTH) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)  {
    //your css here
}
```

Either add this query to your existing, or make a seperate one:

> you can combine multiple media queries in a comma-separated list; if any of the media queries in the list is true, the associated style sheet is applied. This is the equivalent of a logical "or" operation.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: i have tried for  this solution but this is also not working on my mac

Comment: Can you post your whole media query?

Comment: @media (min-width:4103px) and (max-width:5464px)
 {
  .lg-square-box {
      height: 300.5px;
  }
  .lg-rectangle-box {
      height: 148.5px;
  }
  .home-menu .row .box {
      margin-bottom: 3.5px;
  }
  .subMenus {
      line-height: 1.20;
  }
 }

Comment: I have used your solutions but in 25% zoom level of chrome on mac this is not working.

Comment: Does  it work if you only check for retina? @media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) If not you might have to check for another pixel ratio or dpi from the link.